# Using ngFor and ngClass to apply mat-elevation

Tags: angular, angular-material, elevation

I'm generating a bunch of buttons with `ngFor` and want to elevate the active buttons. I've implemented a function that will tell if a button needs to be enabled or disabled, and now I'm trying to do:

```
  <mat-button-toggle 
        [ngClass]="isButtonDisabled(button.authLevel, button.id) ? '' : 'mat-elevation-z5'"
        *ngFor="let button of buttonsFromApi" 
        id="{{button.id}}" class="problemButton" 
        [disabled]="isButtonDisabled(button.authLevel, button.id)">
        {{button.displayName}}
      </mat-button-toggle>
```

This however won't work and all the buttons will lay flat. `mat-elevation-z5` is imported correctly as I'm using it on another element that *does* show up with the proper elevation.

Comment: You mean that `mat-alevation-z5` is not applied?

Comment: @StepUp Yes! There's no elevation visible, nor can I see it under the classes when inspecting the element.

Comment: 1. Try to set like this `[ngClass]="['mat-elevation-z5'] and see whether is class applied.
2. Try to set like this `[ngClass]="[isButtonDisabled(button.authLevel, button.id) ? '' : 'mat-elevation-z5']"`

Comment: @StepUp Tried it already, same result.

Comment: Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example?

Comment: can you share with us isButtonDisabled method source code ?

Comment: @malbarmawi You can expect it to always return true (tried and didn't work even with constant Trues).

Comment: hi have you check my answer it work ,so I just want to check your method .

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">

    <mat-button-toggle [ngClass]="{'mat-elevation-z5':!btn.disabled }" 
                     *ngFor="let button of buttonsFromApi" id="{{button}}"
                     class="problemButton" [disabled]="isButtonDisabled(button)" #btn>
        {{button}}
    </mat-button-toggle>

</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

> I use a template reference for button (btn) this will prevent call the
>   `isButtonDisabled` twice

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oftr9h)

Comment: I need it to be `id="{{button.id}}"` because I am referencing it later. The problem is that whatever I add in the `mat-elevation` class gets overwritten by `.mat-button-toggle-standalone.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard`. I think I'll just apply some shadows in my css circumventing `.mat-elevation.`

Comment: `id="{{button}}"` this just mock data but it seem work fine on my demo 